# Wcf trace errors to windows service

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, windows-services

I have a WCF service running on a windows service. I want that any exception raised in the wcf service will get to the windows service so I can write it to the event log.

I have already made an ErrorHandler class which implements IErrorHandler and IServiceBehavior. And an ErrorHandlerElement which implements BehaviorExtensionElement.

How do I add listeners to the service and receive it at the windows service?

Comment: Have you applied your `IServiceBehavior` attribute to WCF service class so error handler receives all errors? Then you can convert them in Faults and pass to the service

Comment: Alright. How do I catch them in the service?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the exception to get to the Windows Service to log it? Typically you want to have the global error handler, IErrorHandler, in WCF handle the exception to avoid the host restarting.

In the past, I've use the EnterpriseLibrary Exception Handling and Logging frameworks ([EntLib5](http://entlib.codeplex.com/)) to capture and log the exceptions. By using a Event Log Trace Listener (the default) you can log the exception in the IErrorHandler and the exception doesn't need to propagate outside of WCF.